# Meteor color-thief package doesn't work

Tags: meteor

I am playing with the "thospaeth:color-thief" package for meteor. 
All I did was to install the package and then define a variable in an event handler:

```
var colorThief = new ColorThief();
```

The error is

```
"Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: ColorThief is not defined
at Object.Template.onePiece.helpers.image (http://localhost:3000/test.js?5fb2bf210aaa5b8ff2677599dea86a243ed2c4ef:689:27)
at bindDataContext (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:2880:16)
at Blaze._wrapCatchingExceptions (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:1651:16)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:2928:66
at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:3476:12)
at wrapHelper (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:2927:27)
at Spacebars.call (http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?7bafbe05ec09b6bbb6a3b276537e4995ab298a2f:172:18)
at Spacebars.mustacheImpl (http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?7bafbe05ec09b6bbb6a3b276537e4995ab298a2f:109:25)
at Object.Spacebars.mustache (http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?7bafbe05ec09b6bbb6a3b276537e4995ab298a2f:113:39)
at null._render (http://localhost:3000/template.test.js?99a11da3988b8831f8e1fc0dcbf93b61fa67d909:281:22)"
```

I tried the other package "benan789:color-thief". It didn't work.
I tried to copied the colorthief.js to the folder then directly include it in the header. It didn't work either.

Did I miss anything?  Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get thospaeth:color-thief working either, but benan789:color-thief works.  Note the meteor usage instructions (https://atmospherejs.com/benan789/color-thief):

> var colorThief = new ColorThief.colorRob();

Your event handler can look something like this:

```
'click button': function () {
  var colorThief = new ColorThief.colorRob();
  // get a handle on an image element
  var headerImage = $('img.headerimage')[0];
  // get the dominant color from the image
  var c = colorThief.getColor(headerImage);
  console.log('color: ' + c);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. I thought I copied the code snippet. Guess I was wrong. :) Thanks for the help.